# I want to create a button in React Native App, which changes the textVaue when press on it and when press one more time, textValue became initial

Tags: react-native

I created a button which changes a textValue onPress, but I don't know how to make that after one more press it will return the textValue to its initial value.

```
this.state = {
    textValue: 'Initial Value',
    }

  this.onPressButton= this.onPressButton.bind(this);
}
 onPressButton() {
    this.setState({
        textValue: 'Second Value',
        
        
    })
}
```

...

```
 <Button onPress= {this.onPressButton}>
                <ButtonText>Change Value</ButtonText>
 </Button>

            <Text>{this.state.textValue}</Text>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `initial`? that if you refresh it still the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a state property `initialValue` and set textValue initially to that value. Perhaps you can also add a state property that keeps track if the button has already been pressed or not.

```
this.state = {
  textValue: 'Initial Value',
  initialTextValue: 'Initial Value',
  buttonHasBeenPressed: false
};
```

Then when pressing the button you can check if the button has already been pressed, if so, you could set the value to the initial value.

```
onPressButton() {
  if (this.state.buttonHasBeenPressed) {
    this.setState({
      textValue: this.state.initialValue
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      textValue: 'Second Value',
      buttonHasBeenPressed: true
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is something like this(?):

```
    this.state = {
        textValue: 'Initial Value',
        initial: true
    }

    this.onPressButton = this.onPressButton.bind(this);

    onPressButton() {
        const textValue = this.state.initial ? 'Second Value' : 'Initial Value';
        this.setState({
            textValue , initial: !this.state.initial
        })
    }
```